# Reorganize Excel Values via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am working on a networking project and I need to output a CSV file for a database consumption. I am pulling a list via WMIC commands on an internal telnet sort of thing. It spits out an excel list of computer hostnames, interface names, IPs and MACAddresses. Unfortunately they are not formatted the best and I need to rearrange the data to produce a CSV file. My output lists the hostname and the interface name and then lists hostname and IP/MAC as listed below. Some machines have more interfaces than others so I can't just count down and copy that to a new cell.

The order of interface name will match up to the IPs and macs though. The output is based on index so I just need to figure out how to merge lines. I am not sure if I can make it into an array or what.  My ideal output would be hostname, Interface Name, IP, MAC. I am just not sure how to go about rearrange the data. The plan will be to have code in a VBA macro that will do the reorganization. Any suggestions on the best method to rearrange? Thanks

```
computer1,InterfaceName 1  
computer1,InterfaceName 2  
computer1,InterfaceName 3  
computer1,InterfaceName 4  
computer1,{"127.0.0.1"} 00:00:00:00:00:01  
computer1,{"127.0.0.2"} 00:00:00:00:00:02  
computer1,{"127.0.0.3"} 00:00:00:00:00:03  
computer1,{"127.0.0.4"} 00:00:00:00:00:04  
computer2,InterfaceName 1  
computer2,InterfaceName 2  
computer2,{"127.0.0.1"} 00:00:00:00:00:01   
computer2,{"127.0.0.2"} 00:00:00:00:00:02
```

I hope to get something like this.

```
computer1,InterfaceName 1,127.0.0.1, 00:00:00:00:00:01
computer1,InterfaceName 2,127.0.0.2, 00:00:00:00:00:02
computer1,InterfaceName 3,127.0.0.3, 00:00:00:00:00:03
computer1,InterfaceName 4,127.0.0.4, 00:00:00:00:00:04
computer2,InterfaceName 1,127.0.0.1, 00:00:00:00:00:01
computer2,InterfaceName 2,127.0.0.2, 00:00:00:00:00:02
```

This is what I eventually came up with.

```
'Gather last row
Dim iRow As Long
iRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'split column in two, A: Hostnames,Interface B:IP,Mac
Range("A1").Select
Dim test As Integer
For i = iRow To 1 Step -1
If InStr(Cells(i, 1), "{") Then
Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
End If
Next

Range("A1").Select

'delete blank spaces and move up
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iRow, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp

Range("A1").Select
iRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'format B: Column
Dim iPos As Integer
Dim sValue As String
For i = iRow To 1 Step -1
sValue = ""
'remove Hostname and leave comma
iPos = InStr(Cells(i, 2), ",")
sValue = Mid(Cells(i, 2).Value, iPos)
'add command between IP and MAC
iPos = InStr(sValue, "}")
sValue = Left(sValue, iPos) & "," & Right(sValue, Len(sValue) - iPos)
'remove brackets and quotes
sValue = Replace(sValue, "{", "")
sValue = Replace(sValue, "}", "")
sValue = Replace(sValue, """", "")

'merge cells
Cells(i, 1).Value = Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) & Trim(sValue)

'delete B: cell
Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If the example data you provided is representative of the actual data I would use a two step approach. First I would split the data into two separate lists. One list for all the hostname/interface names and a second one for the hostname/ip/mac. Splitting could be done as easily as detecting if the second column starts with '{'.

You should get the lists like below:

**Interfaces**

```
computer1,InterfaceName 1  
computer1,InterfaceName 2  
computer1,InterfaceName 3  
computer1,InterfaceName 4
computer2,InterfaceName 1  
computer2,InterfaceName 2
```

**Addresses**

```
computer1,{"127.0.0.1"} 00:00:00:00:00:01  
computer1,{"127.0.0.2"} 00:00:00:00:00:02  
computer1,{"127.0.0.3"} 00:00:00:00:00:03  
computer1,{"127.0.0.4"} 00:00:00:00:00:04  
computer2,{"127.0.0.1"} 00:00:00:00:00:01   
computer2,{"127.0.0.2"} 00:00:00:00:00:02
```

Once you have that you can merge them based on index. It may not be the most efficient way, but it seems to be the simplest method to me.